# Is it necessary to use non-blocking file descriptors with IO multiplexing?

Tags: c, unix, io, network-programming, posix

Posix supports blocking and non-blcoking file descriptors. Second ones may be opened with `O_NONBLOCK` flag. I have a main loop in my app, which polls some set (`poll` sys call) of file descriptors for `POLLIN` and `POLLOUT` events. May I still use blocking file descriptors, cause I write only when `POLLOUT` is set and read only when `POLLIN` is set?

Answer (score 5):

Accroding to poll(2) man page:

> **POLLOUT** Writing is now possible, though a write larger that the available space in a socket or pipe will still block (unless O_NONBLOCK is set).

In other words: if there is not enough space in kernel buffer associated with this fd, writing a chunk of data, larger than space available in buffer would block. If there is space available they behave identically.

So you must set all your file descriptors to be non-blocking, especially TCP sockets, cause if the process on the other side has slow connection you may face blocking write call, until client won't send you back all ACKs for every IP package.

Comment: Reading can be a problem too, in Linux at least. See [this kernel mailing list thread](https://lkml.org/lkml/2004/10/6/117) where it was reported as a bug. The kernel developers said, regardless of the literal reading of POSIX, it's not going to be changed and you should use `O_NONBLOCK`.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley: That bug was eventually fixed.

Comment: @R.. Wow, that's a surprise, considering the tone of the discussion in that mailing list thread. But I guess 13 years can change anything.